# How to get text from web element where didn't have unic id or class in selenium java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I want to ask how to get the text from element where didnt have unic id/class, i tried using xpath(copied from web browser) but it's not working this is the picture.

[image: this is the picture]

Comment: Please add page source and don't attach images in questions until they are some error messages.

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try below code;

```
("//*[@class='col-sm-4']//*[@class='text-grey'][1]").getText();
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(driver.getPageSource());
Elements content = doc.select("span[class^=text-grey]");
ArrayList<String> allTextIntextGreyClass = (ArrayList<String>) content.eachText();
```

Then you can work with ArrayList to get the text you want to work with, or you can work with "content". If this does not work, you can get the inner HTML and work with it to get the right context you want. You can get innerHTML as follows:

```
String inHTML = driver.findElement(By.className("text-grey")).getAttribute("innerHTML");
```